# How to sort the text field that contains alpha numeric characters separated by period delimiter?

Tags: postgresql-9.5

I have a requirement to sort the field in natural sort fashion but unable to achieve this. Is there a way to achieve this?

This is for PostgreSQL code remediation and tried various code snippets but none of them returns the rows as expected

-- PostgresSQL 9.5 code

```
SELECT name
FROM (
  SELECT lower('1.1.1.a.1') as name union all
  SELECT lower('1.1.a.1') as name union all
  SELECT lower('1.1.1.a.11') as name
) folders
ORDER BY
COALESCE(SUBSTRING(name FROM '^(\\d+)')::INTEGER, 99999999),
SUBSTRING(name FROM '^\\d* *(.*?)( \\d+)?$'),
COALESCE(SUBSTRING(name FROM ' (\\d+)$')::INTEGER, 0),
name;
```

I expect the output to be sorted in the following order

```
Expected Output:
================
1.1.a.1
1.1.1.a.1
1.1.1.a.11

Actual (current) Output:
========================
1.1.1.a.1
1.1.1.a.11
1.1.a.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first sort by length, then by an array created from the elements:

```
SELECT name
FROM (
  values 
    ('1.1.1.a.1'), ('1.1.a.1'), ('1.1.1.a.11'), ('1.1.1.a.2')
) folders (name)
ORDER BY length(name), string_to_array(name, '.');
```

returns

```
name      
----------
1.1.a.1   
1.1.1.a.1 
1.1.1.a.2
1.1.1.a.11
```

Not sure if this covers all cases